# Getting CORS / Origin Error When Calling External API

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs

I have a react app without a backend that is using `localhost`. In a component, there is an `onClick` handler which calls an external API to get data. The state is amended to have a piece of state be the return value of the API.

The code for that call:

```
fetch(statsURL)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.resultSets.rowSet
    })
```

This generates the following error:
[image]

In the Network details, I do get a 200 OK status code, and here is the header info:
[image]

Let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) to request resources that are not served with CORS headers. To get the response from a `fetch()` call use `Response.text()`, `Response.json()`, `Response.blob()` or `Response.arrayBuffer()`

```
fetch(statsURL)
.then(function(response) {
  return response.json()
})
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data.resultSets.rowSet)
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I added this code to my file, and still get the same error in the console.

Comment: @jsc42 Are you using YQL to request the resource?